# pygtk popup executes out of order

Tags: python, pygtk

I have pygtk menu, in which a function is called on menuitem click, in this function i am showing a popup to user saying wait while checking internet connectivity and then calling a function which checks internet connectivity,

My problem is the my programs is first calling the internet connectivity check function and then after completion of function call it shows me popup,

I tried putting,

```
 while gtk.events_pending():     
      gtk.main_iteration_do(False)
```

It shows blur popup which hangs till my function call is completed and then gets clear.

my code looks something like,

```
dialog = gtk.MessageDialog(
        parent         = None,
        flags          = gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
        type           = gtk.MESSAGE_INFO,
        buttons        = gtk.BUTTONS_NONE,
        message_format = None)
        dialog.set_markup("Please wait while checking internet connectivity")
        dialog.set_title('Checking internet')
        dialog.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        dialog.connect('response', self.show_hide, dialog )
        dialog.show()
        gobject.timeout_add(5, self.show_hide, dialog)
 try :
        netStatus = check_network()
 except Exception, excp:
        print excp
```

Can somebody tell me whats wrong??
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The main loop calls your handler for the menu item and waits for it to return before it does anything else, including dismissing the menu so your dialog can get the focus.

The easiest workaround might be to use timeout_add to call your connection check when the main loop gets around to it, i.e. after showing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor check_network() to make it non-blocking.

Instead of making a blocking call on some socket, use [gobject.io_add_watch()](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--io-add-watch) to register a callback that will be be notified as soon as data is ready for the socket. In this callback, you can update or destroy the popup.

On Linux GTK will most likely use the [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) system call behind the scene, which can wait on any number of file descriptor events with a timeout, including sockets and FIFOs (in case you are spawning a subprocess).

This concept is called "event-based programming". You have only a single thread of execution. Almost every GUI framework works this way. The idea is that you never do anything that might take longer than a few milliseconds. It's a great concept, because it avoids all the hairy problems that arise with synchronization of truly concurrent threads.